# Two uneven groups (101 vs 21) measured twice; what repeated measures ANOVA equivalent can help?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric

I have a question that I have difficulties in answering:
I have two groups of patients tested twice at the same continuous variable.
Group A=104 & GroupB=21.
So two groups, one continuous variable, measured twice. Due to the uneveness of the samples I think that repeated measures ANOVA is not suitable.

Is there another way of testing the patient groups differences? Maybe a non-parametric equivalent?
I prefer an SPSS solution, but I could use R as well.

Thanks in advance.